# Duplicated content on homepage

Tags: path-aliases

I've found that my site is showing duplicated content, I think it was when I installed Pathauto. The nodes are not duplicated though but seems to be multiple aliases.

I've since tried using Global Redirect but it hasn't solved the issue. And even worse, some items are showing up three times now!

For example

http://biosphericproject.php5.demo.faelix.net/content/what-we-mean-forest-gardening-1
http://biosphericproject.php5.demo.faelix.net/content/what-we-mean-forest-gardening
http://biosphericproject.php5.demo.faelix.net/content/what-we-mean-forest-gardening-0

Confused,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete those duplicate alias by going to the alias list at admin/config/search/path (in Drupal 7). It's not an automatic task, I'm afraid.
Or you can delete all alias and bulk recreate them using the Bulk Update function. That would be an automatic process.

As a last step, you should check Alias Settings at admin/config/search/path/settings. I think you should change the "Update action" to "Create a new alias. Delete the old alias.".

Comment: Thanks - I went to that page and there were four links for each item! Something weird was going on... I realised that the Feeds module was importing content each time I ran cron

Comment: I'd vote you up but the "register account" button isn't working, it just sends me round in a loop back to the homepage, and the Google sign in button does the same!